# How to find the converging value of the following voltage series (or at least the general term)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

In my circuit theory class, while solving for the steady state voltage of a certain circuit I came across a certain voltage series.

The terms of the series are:

$V_1 = 5 + (0 - 5)e^{-1/k}$

$V_2 = 10 + (V_1 - 10)e^{-1/k}$

$V_3 = 15 + (V_2 - 15)e^{-1/k}$

And so on...

Where $k$ is a constant positive real number.

I think I'll get a recursion like $V_n = 5n + (V_{n-1} - 5n)e^{-1/k}$

I couldn't find the converging value of this series, because first of all I'm not sure how to find the general term of the series. Any idea about how to approach this problem? Will the series even converge?

Comment: If it is given that it converges, then let $V_n = V_{n-1} = L$ and solve for $L$. From this you get $L = 5n$ but that means $L $ diverges

Comment: @KingTut Yeah, just realized that part. However, still not sure about how to find the general term.

Comment: I think general term is $V_n = 5\cdot n - 5\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}e^{-r/k}-e^{-n/k}$

Comment: @KingTut You could please write the proof in an answer below. I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I only found $V_2, V_3$ and this fit in. It can be easily shown using induction. There was an error in last comment, it should be $V_n = 5n - 5\sum_{r=1}^{n}e^{-r/k}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding first few terms, $V_1 = 5 - 5e^{-1/k}$, $V_2 = 5-5e^{-1/k}-5e^{-2/k}$ etc, we come up with the hypotheses $p(n)$ that $$V_n = 5(n-\sum_{r=1}^{n}e^{-1/k})$$

Base case is covered. So for the induction step let this be true for $n = j$. So $V_j = 5(j-\sum_{r=1}^{j}e^{-1/k})$

$$\begin{align}V_{j+1} &= 5(j+1) + (V_j - 5(j+1))e^{-1/k}\\
 V_{j+1} &= 5(j+1) + (5j-5\sum_{r=1}^{j}e^{-1/k}- 5j-5))e^{-1/k}\\
 &=  5(j+1) -5\sum_{r=1}^{j+1}e^{-1/k} \\
& = 5\left((j+1) - \sum_{r=1}^{j+1}e^{-1/k}\right)
\end{align}$$

Thus $p(j) \implies  p(j+1)$.